# Colormap and colorbar for 3d trajectory. (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm looking to do something similar to the below image ([source](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8121/abb167/meta)) in Matlab. Ignore the vectors and the shaded cone; I just want to

1. plot a trajectory on the unit sphere, given by a function `m(x)` (whose values are points on the sphere),
2. color it according to parameter `x` (running from `-inf` to `+inf`),
3. display a color bar which explains the mapping from `x`-value to color.

[image]

I can plot the sphere easily with the help of built-in functions `sphere` and `mesh`, and I can draw the trajectory with `plot3`. To generate the `x`-values I can use something like

```
x = tan((-1:0.01:1)*pi/2);
```

which gives a distribution of points fitting for the types of functions `m(x)` will be (most of the action will be around `x = 0`).

The tricky part is the color. I have looked at the `colormap` and `colorbar` built-ins, but both seem to pertain to meshes and surfaces rather than curves, so I don't see an obvious way to adapt it to my use case.

Does anyone have any ideas for how I might proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `plot` it is not possible for one line to be multicoloured. In order to make one line multicoloured, you must plot each individual segment and then colour them individually. For example:

```
% make some dummy data
% note that this is in the form of 1 x N row vectors
t = -.99:0.01:0.99;
x = cos(t * pi/2); 
y = sin(t * pi/2);
z = t;

% reorder data in order to plot individual line segments
indices = [1:length(x) - 1; 2:length(x)];
figure; 
p = plot3(x(indices), y(indices), z(indices), 'LineWidth', 2);
set(p, {'Color'}, num2cell(parula(length(x) - 1), 2)); % see what happens when you comment out this line
```

You can change the `colormap` you want by changing the `parula` keyword above. You can use any of the supplied colormaps, or create your own (in the form of an M x 3 RGB triple matrix).

You can then add the colorbar (note that these are dummy values).

```
c = colorbar;
caxis([-6 6]);
set(c, 'Ticks', [-6, -4, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6]);
set(c, 'TickLabels', {'-\infty', '-4', '-2', '-1', '0', '1', '2', '4', '\infty'});
```

Comment: This looks good! One issue; If I change the `colormap` from the default `parula` to, say, `jet`, how do I make this change in the `colorbar` as well? I have looked in the documentation for a `colormap` property on the `colorbar` object, but there doesn't seem to be one. As is, the `colormap` defaults to `parula`.

Comment: Thanks ummg, good point! You can change the colormap using the `colormap` command [see here](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) e.g. add in the line `colormap(jet)` before creating the colorbar.

Comment: Ah, perfect! Don't know why I did not think to try that; I guess I was too focused on the idea that the colormap should be a property of the colorbar. The implicit class hierarchies in matlab figures/axes/colormaps etc. are a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a somewhat similar, but different, effect using `scatter3()`.  It is similar to plot3() but will allow you to set color (and size, if you wish) for each data point that it plots.  If the aesthetics suit you, it is a simple and versatile approach.

Comment: Yes, I did look at that option, but I found that the step size required for a good looking plot was nonideal.